# How can I make my garbage disposal outlet work for other electric devices?

Tags: electrical, garbage-disposal

I want to install the charging station for a battery-powered "Dirt Devil" vacuum cleaner under the kitchen sink. There's an outlet there which the garbage disposal plugs into, so I thought I would just add an outlet multiplier and plug them both in. But when I plugged my drill directly into the outlet to test this idea, the drill didn't work. Is the garbage disposal outlet (USA) not compatible with standard electric devices? Is there something simple I can do to make this work?

Comment: It will be live when you turn on the disposer. It can be wired so it can work as you wish I believe. But it will take a rewiring.... Actually a wire relocation in the box.... this wire goes here instead of here, this tab breaks between here and there and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this you can remove the switch and splice the wires thru so the receptacle is hot all the time. You can then install one of these: [Sink top air switch.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BQO9XM)